# How to save output in python to .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

So basically i bought a book that teaches the basics of python and how to create a random number generator so I decided to go one step further and make a random password generator I found a tutorial online that gave me a good example of why and what is used to make a password generator but i want the output to be saved to a .txt file I do not know what i need to implement to get the result i want this is what i have i'm using python3.

```
import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!, @,#$%^&*.'

number = input('Number of passwords - ')
number = int(number)

length = input('password length? - ')
length = int(length)

answer = input

for P in range(number):
    password = ''
for C in range(length):
    password += random.choice(chars)
    print(password)


password = open("passlist.txt", "a")
password.write(password)
password.close()

file = open('passlist', 'w')
file.write(password)
file.close()
```

this is what i get in shell

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\User\Desktop\passgen.py", line 21, in <module>
        password.write(password)
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: You are calling both your password string `password` **AND** the file object `password`. Change one of them...

Comment: Use a different variable name for your file object. `password = open(...)` overwrites the password you generated.

Comment: As an aside, you assigned the input function to a variable: `answer = input`. There is no reason to do this.

Comment: Put your password generator in a function and call that function as many times as you like to generate more passwords.

Comment: i got rid of the answer = input thanks now would the function be a global var because i tried to make a menu so that i could import the password generator is this similar to what your explaining but without the menu part ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, since the issue is simply that two variables had the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new file and set it equal to a variable, you are actually creating an *_io.TextIOWrapper* object. So in this line of code, you are creating this object and storing it in *password*, getting rid of the password generated in the previous lines of code.

`password = open("passlist.txt", "a")`

You are then trying to write to the passlist.txt file with this line:

`password.write(password)`

You are telling password, now an *_io.TextIOWrapper* object, to write to the passfile.txt the *_io.TextIOWrapper* object, not the password generated beforehand. This function is expecting a string, and you are now passing an *_io.TextIOWrapper* object. Since password is no longer a string, that is why you are running into the error.

To fix this, I would suggest creating a new variable:

```
txtFileWriter = open("passlist.txt", "a")
txtFileWriter.write(password)
txtFileWriter.close()
```

You may find that after fixing this, only one value is being stored inside your text file. I would recommend properly nesting your for loops:

```
for P in range(number):
    password = ''
    for C in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    print(password)
```

The meaning of these for loops can be translated as:
For each password, set the password = ' ' and for each character, add one random character to password.

The problem with this is that you will only have one password after the for loops are complete. You are setting the password value to ' ' each time you run through the outer loop. The only password that will be saved, will be the last value. In order to fix this, I recommend using a list.

I recommend reading through this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

I don't want to spoon feed the answers since I realize you are learning python, so I will leave it here. You will want to create a list and then append a value to that list each time you generate a password. After some reading, hopefully this will make sense.

Comment: thanks mate and thank you for your explanation :) but if i select to generate 2 passwords it will only generate 1 why is this ?

Comment: I just edited my post, explaining it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'passlist.txt'
with open (filename, 'a') as file_object:
    file_object.write(password)
```

Using **with** will close the file once access is no longer needed.

You also need a list to append your passwords ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error originates from password being re-assigned in `password = open("passlist.txt", "a")`. This causes and error in the next line as you are attempting to pass `password` as parameter to itself in `password.write(password)`.

**Some farther assistance**

You have the right idea but you forgot to indent. All the lines below `for P in range(number):` should be indented because the program must generate and write a new password until it has satisfied the required amount of passwords.

The `password = open("passlist.txt", "a")`
`password.write(password)`
`password.close()` lines are unnecessary as you are overriding the generated password and assigning that password variable to something that is not a string; that is why you are getting that error.

Here is the code with the adjustments.

```
import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!, @,#$%^&*.'

number = input('Number of passwords - ')
number = int(number)

length = input('password length? - ')
length = int(length)

answer = input

for P in range(number):
    password = ''
    for C in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)

    print(password)
    password += "\n" # writes the password in a new line

    file = open('passlist.tx', "a")
    file.write(password)
    file.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your feed back and explanation im going to do a it more reading :)

Comment: this is the out come i was looking for and after a bit of research im a bit more educated thank you im going to keep diving deeper in to python. do i have to close the discussion and i so how would i do so?

Comment: @jkfrn._ there should be an option to accept the answer somewhere.